# React router redirect not working when I try to access other routes while logged out

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am trying to redirect if to the login screen if the user is not logged in. I implemented a private route to handle this functionality as follows

```
import React from "react";
import { Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import isAuth from "./isAuth";

function ProtectedRoute({ component: Component, ...rest }) {
  const auth = false;
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={(props) => {
        auth === true ? <Component {...props} /> : <Redirect to="/login" />;
      }}
    />
  );
}

export default ProtectedRoute;
```

However, it doesn't redirect to the login screen. Here is my index.js code as well

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Router>
    <HODNav />
    <Route path="/login" exact component={Login} />
    <ProtectedRoute path="/changeDayOff" exact component={SendDayOffRequest} />
    <ProtectedRoute path="/" exact component={ViewMyProfile} />
    <ProtectedRoute path="/resetPassword" exact component={ResetPassowrd} />
    <ProtectedRoute path="/attendance" exact component={ViewAttendance} />
    <ProtectedRoute path="/courseSlots" exact component={CourseSlots} />
    <ProtectedRoute
      path="/login/CI/viewSlotsAssignment"
      exact
      component={viewSlotsAssignment}
    />
    <ProtectedRoute
      path="/login/CI/viewAllStaff"
      exact
      component={viewAllStaff}
    />
    <ProtectedRoute
      path="/login/coursesListView"
      exact
      component={CoursesListView}
    />
    <ProtectedRoute
      path="/slotLinkingRequests"
      exact
      component={SlotLinkingRequests}
    />
    <ProtectedRoute path="/staffAttendance" exact component={StaffAttendance} />
  </Router>,

  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Comment: I see you've hardcoded the `auth` value to false, I don't see how  the truthy path could be taken at all to not actually return and render the redirect. Think you could create a *running* codesandbox that you could share with us?

Comment: Although it’s hard to answer this on my phone I think the problem here is you’re not returning anything from the route render prop. Try adding parenthesis around the renders code block.

Comment: I think @KyleLambert is absolutely correct, you need to `return auth ? <Component {...props} /> : <Redirect to="/login" />;` from the render function.

Comment: After reading over this again, I don't think adding parenthesis will work. As per @Drew Reese the solution is to return from the turnery operator.